# Except in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have to lists. One that contains all the valid chapter codes(chpt_cd) and their associated appl src codes. i.e the list is

```
List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>
```

The base model class is

```
public class ChapterCodeValidationOutput
{
    public string chpt_cd { get; set; }
    public string appl_src_cd { get; set; }
}
```

The list sample data is ..

```
chpt_cd    aapl_src_cd
-------    -----------

07038      C062
07038      C062
06206      C191
```

And another list contains invalid chapter codes only.

`List<string>`

only.

And it's sample data is '06206'

I have to find the associated appl_src_cd of the invalid chapter codes list i.e. 'C191' and so on . The returned should be a list only.

Comment: It seems there are duplicate `chpt_cd` values in the first list. What happens if the corresponding `aapl_src_cd` values are different?

Comment: They wont be different .

Comment: `var SelectedChapters = Chapters.Where(w => InvalidChapters.Contains(w.chpt_cd)).ToList();`

Comment: @Plutonix, if the lists are large, then this will be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Except` will not help you in this case.

Assuming that these are the lists:

```
List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput> list1 = ...
List<string> list2 = ...
```

Then you can create a lookup from the first list for fast lookup like this:

```
var lookup = list1.ToLookup(x => x.chpt_cd, x => x.appl_src_cd);
```

And then use it like this to get the list of corresponding codes:

```
var result = list2.Select(x => lookup[x].First()).ToList();
```

I am assuming (since you mentioned in the comments), that if there are duplicate `chpt_cd` values, the corresponding `appl_src_cd` values will be equal.

Comment: `ToDictionary` call will throw `ArgumentException`, since there are duplicate chpt_cd's in the first list in the given example.

Comment: @stop-cran, Right. I didn't see that before

Comment: @stop-cran, question updated to use a lookup instead of a dictionary